# Angular resolve user on startup

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Hoping this is an easy one!

I want to make sure the user accessing the application is resolved before showing any screens or calling any subsequent services.

I can resolve the user through making a HTTP REST call using a token that will already be present on the first request.

This user is then passed into subsequent rest calls e.g. a REST service to "get my work".

I know I could use a resolve function on my routing but for this to work I'd have to add it into every single routing since I can't always guarantee users will come in via the front door.

I tried putting it into a main controller that spans the whole application but the problem here is that the routing resolve is called first which needs the user to do it's REST calls.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Kevin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similair problem before and I was lucky enough to come across [this](https://github.com/mrgamer/angular-login-example) example project.

We've got 2 projects

1. One has a home brewed auth mechanism consisting of an external app, server-side credential checking, then being redirected to the internal app.
2. and another (very prototype-ish) using the example project's concepts... so far I've been preferring this approach.

**In project A we basically do something to this extent.**

> Write a userToken inside the cookie, if the cookie exists (& is valid) on return... job done.
> If not, Please log in so we can create the cookie.

**But my suggested route is to follow Project B:**

> You'll basically need an interim app/state where you can do your
> initial check, if your user isnt entering via the normal login routes.

I've shamelesly stolen this graph below from the awesome mrgamer's angular-login example project.
His project can be found at [here](https://github.com/mrgamer/angular-login-example).

[image: Authflow]

```
angular.module('angular-login.pages', ['angular-login.grandfather'])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app.admin', {
      url: '/admin',
      templateUrl: 'pages/admin.tpl.html',
      accessLevel: accessLevels.admin
    })
    .state('app.user', {
      url: '/user',
      templateUrl: 'pages/user.tpl.html',
      accessLevel: accessLevels.user
    });
});
```

The documentation is quite verbose and should explain some of the intricacies of the whole approach

### OR

And I'm not as familiar with this approach (as I haven't tried it in a fully fledged app). You could perform a check on the `$routeChangeStart`

```
angular.module('angular-client-side-auth', ['ngCookies'])  
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        if (!Auth.authorize(next.access)) {
            if(Auth.isLoggedIn()) $location.path('/');
            else                  $location.path('/login');
        }
    });

}]);
```

Source from [here](http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/)

Comment: Thanks for the docs. So If I understand correctly, basically have a parent abstract route that resolves the user? All other routes then extend this?